# QT Modal Window and Disabling parents toolbar

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, toolbar

I am developing a project using Qt4 and I have run into a slight issue.
I am creating a modal window from the main window. I want this to disable the toolbar at the top. 
I have a menu item that spawns the modal from the menu. What I want is that when the modal is spawned that menus is disabled. I have tried using the setEnabled(false) function but that doesn't reset it.

Here is the code:

```
void Main_Screen::Create_ViPro()
{
   std::auto_ptr<ViPro_Dialog> modal(new ViPro_Dialog(this));
   modal->show();
   modal->exec();
}
```

So It is just a simple class that is triggered when a menu item is selected. I feel that the problem stems from the fact that i'm setting the parent to the main screen, however I don't know how to create a modal without a parent(it doesn't make sense to do that). Is there a way to disable the parents toolbar from the child? The only thing I have seen so far is _fileMenu->setEnabled(false);
That works as long as I don't create the modal, but as soon as that is spawned, the menu works again. I'm totally lost.
Thanks in advance

Edit as Patrice

Here is the constructor

```
    Main_Screen::Main_Screen(QWidget* parent /*= NULL*/) 
                        : QMainWindow(parent),
                          _newProj(new QAction(tr("New &ViPro"), this)),
                          _fileMenu(menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File")))
{    
  //create slot for creating a new project
  connect(_newProj.get(), SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(Create_ViPro()));
  _fileMenu->addAction(_newProj.get());
  //if i do this then setEnabled(false) works perfectly and i can't access the menu
  Create_ViPro()
}
```

So the function is signaled by triggering the newproject action. If i call the function directly from within the constructor it disables it as you stated patrice, however, if I have the function called via the trigger, it doesn't disable it. Am I handling the signal / slot mechanism wrong?  Thanks again.

Another example, if I make the function create_vipro() as below

```
void Main_Screen::Create_ViPro()
{
     _fileMenu->setEnabled(false);
}
```

The file menu isn't disabled when I trigger the event, so it must have nothing to do with the modal itself, but instead how signals are handled.

Comment: From which QT classes are `Main_Screen` and `ViPro_Dialog` derived?

Comment: Main_Screen is derived from QMainWindow, and ViPro_Dialog is derived from QDialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since child is a modal dialog main screen can't react to event. But you can disable the toolbar (or menubar) before creating the modal dialog and enable it as soon as you leave the exec function:

```
void Main_Screen::Create_ViPro()
{
   _fileMenu->setEnabled(false);

   std::auto_ptr<ViPro_Dialog> modal(new ViPro_Dialog(this));
   modal->show();
   modal->exec(); // Will stay here until you close the modal dialog

   _fileMenu->setEnabled(true);
}
```

if ViPro_Dialog is really a modal dialog it will works.

Another thing, since ViPro_Dialog is modal you can declare it locally without using auto_ptr:

```
void Main_Screen::Create_ViPro()
{
   _fileMenu->setEnabled(false);

   ViPro_Dialog modal(this);
   modal.show();
   modal.exec(); // Will stay here until you close the modal dialog

   _fileMenu->setEnabled(true);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I guess (I can't test at work) that you can't enable/disable menu when it is executing a QAction. Signal is calling slots sequentially so QAction is busy when you try to disable the menu.
Try this:

1. In Main Screen, create a slot with one boolean parameter that enable/disable menubar. Just call the setEnabled function
2. In ViPro_Dialog, emit a signal with a boolean parameter (false at startup, true at validation)
3. In Create_ViPro, once dialog created, connect the new signal with the slot, exec dialog and don't forget to disconnect slot from signal:

void Main_Screen::Create_ViPro()
{
   ViPro_Dialog modal(this);

// Connect signal/slot

modal.show();
   modal.exec(); // Will stay here until you close the modal dialog

// Disconnect signal/slot
}

This can achieve what you want

**EDIT2**

You are doing a mistake when using modal dialog. There's a conflict between `show()` and `exec()`. When you are displaying modal dialog you don't need to disable other windows: it's automatically done by modal status of the dialog. There are many modal depth: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowModality-enum. So your code should be:

```
void Main_Screen::Create_ViPro()
{
   ViPro_Dialog modal(this);

   // modal.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal); // Uncomment this line if you want to only disable parent

   modal.exec();
}
```

Read this for more detail: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QDialog.html#details.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure, I was doing a tutorial and it said never allocate on the stack because it messes with some destructors. Anyway, I tried this solution and it seems that there is an issue with when a function is called from a signal/slot connection. If I call the funtion Create_ViPro from say the constructor it works perfectly. As soon as I call it by trapping the Signal created when I hit the menu  item the setEnabled no longer seems to work? My theory is that it has to do with using the toolbar to generate the signal, any thought on that?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample to see what' can be wrong with it?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to test this out right now, if it works I will let you know and give you a green check :)

Comment: I tried what you suggested and created a signal that would emit a false and connected it to a signal that set the menu enabled to the value it received from the signal, still couldn't set it's enabled to false. I even tried creating a separate button that would just set it to false when pressed and that didn't work either. It seems to have to do with the signal/slot system itself =/ I am not sure why it wouldn't work with a separate entity signaling it.

Comment: Is your signal/slot connection working? In QtCreator you can check output. If connection is not working a warning message will be displayed

Comment: It is working, I can print messages from the slot and the parameter is working with a quick cout << (status ? "true":"false") << endl. I get the correct values. So everything in the slot is functioning but the setenabled function.

Comment: I was messing around with what you posted and came to the conclusion it has to do with the parent. When I set the parent it seems to be duplicating the tool bar, if I don't set the parent (passing this to the constructor) it doesn't show the file menu anymore. The solution you posted seems work as long as I don't set the parent. I am going to keep messing around with it to see if there is a way to get both to work at the same time, setting the parent and having the modality set. I think I am misunderstanding the parent relationship.

Comment: I don't understand your problem here. Can you post some sceenshots?

Comment: sure, I can get some. To summerize, I think it has to do with using the default toolbar in the mainwindow instead of making my own. I will get some screenshots and post for you today.  Thank you for all the help so far.

Comment: Ok so after much tinkering I think the only solution is to not give the dialog a parent. If I give it a parent then it inherits the QMenuBar. For some reason it is impossible to setEnabled(false) on a menubar from a function called via a signal. It might just be a bug in QT. I was able to set up a button that was disabled from the slot, meaning that it is possible to disable some things from a QAction in a menu. Thanks for all the help but it seems to be a problem from setting a parent OR a bug. Edit - marking this as correct so that anyone else needing it can read our discussion.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure it's a bug since this works for me. Don't set parent avoid to have a window modal dialog but only an application modal dialog.

Comment: The issue stems from the signal setup used by Qt. Basically for some reason the setEnabled function doesn't work on toolbars when a slot is triggered by some signal. You can disable other elements like buttons, but toolbars don't seem to work. If you call them in the c++ way (I tested this from a the constructor) it will disable the toolbar. So if the way it is called changes functionality it seems that it must be some type of problem with the signal handling. I don't know why it happens but it is the best i can explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `exec()` doesn't just create a modal dialog, it also suspends most of the regular event handling, and only handles events in the dialog that is in `exec()`.  This may include some UI updates (like the transitions from enabled to disabled), but I'm not positive.  A better way to handle this might be to explicitly set the dialog modal, but allow the regular event loop to continue, something like this:

```
void Main_Screen::Create_ViPro()
{
   ViPro_Dialog* modal = new ViPro_Dialog(this);
   modal->setModal(true);
   modal->show();
}
```

That code will still not visually disable the toolbar or menubar, but they should be unresponsive.  To disable them, you could try combining this with [Patrice Bernassola's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10189814/9876).